# How close from a bus stop sign am I allowed to park my car in Washington state?

Tags: united-states, driving, washington

I wonder how close from a bus stop sign  I am allowed to park my car in Washington state. If that depends on the city, I'm interested in Spokane. If that depends on the county, I'm interested in Spokane County.

[RCW 46.61.570](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=46.61.570) mentions a few parking regulations but it doesn't specify bus stops. E.g.:

> no person shall:
> (a) Stop, stand, or park a vehicle:
>
> - (i) In front of a public or private driveway or within five feet of the end of the curb radius leading thereto;
> - (ii) Within fifteen feet of a fire hydrant;
> - (iii) Within twenty feet of a crosswalk;
> - (iv) Within thirty feet upon the approach to any flashing signal, stop sign, yield sign, or traffic control signal located at the side of a roadway;
> - (v) Within twenty feet of the driveway entrance to any fire station and on the side of a street opposite the entrance to any fire station within seventy-five feet of said entrance when properly signposted; or
> - (vi) At any place where official signs prohibit standing. [...]
> - (c) Park a vehicle, whether occupied or not, except temporarily for the purpose of and while actually engaged in loading or unloading property or passengers:
> - (i) Within fifty feet of the nearest rail of a railroad crossing;

Example of bus stop (ignore the fire hydrant):

[image]

[image]